# find all $f:R\to R$,and $f(f(x-y))=f(x)-f(y)+f(x)f(y)-xy$

Tags: functions

Find all function $f:R\to R$ that satisfy 
$$f(f(x-y))=f(x)-f(y)+f(x)f(y)-xy$$

Let $y=x$,then
$$f(f(0))=f^2(x)-x^2\Longrightarrow f(x)=\pm \sqrt{x^2+d},\forall x\in R$$
so we have $d\ge 0$,otherwise we couldn't extract square root for $x=0$.

But I can't find the $d$ Thanks

Comment: Put it back in the equation. $\pm\sqrt{|d|+d}=f(f(0))=f^2(x)-x^2=d$, get the values for $d$ and after that always check in the original equation.

Comment: so $d=0$ or $d=2?$  this two value is solution,or there only one such this

Comment: I don't know. I haven't checked. Potentially none of them gives a solution. You need to check if the resulting formula for $f$ satisfies the original equation.